# Controlling the look of Labels in SwiftUI Pickers

Tags: swiftui

I'm curious, is there a way to control how Label views are expressed in SwiftUI Pickers? Of course, one of the features of SwiftUI is that controls express themselves in different ways in different contexts (eg form vs not-form, iOS vs macOS, in toolbar vs out of toolbar).

Normally this feature is desirable, but in my situation, I find the disconnect of how the same label looks in the following three contexts to be a bit jarring:

1. When displaying the current selection of a Picker.

[image: Selection Context]

2. When displaying the choices available in the Picker menu.

[image: Menu Context]

3. When simply displaying information in a form.

[image: Form Context]

In particular, 1 vs 2 is jarring. It doesn't seem right that the user chooses something from picker menu, where the SFSymbol is on the right, and the selection is shown with the SFSymbol on the left. And the way the label looks in context 1, the picker selection, is unattractive to me. The symbol and text are uncomfortably close.

Is there a way to override the default expressions so these differences are less jarring in this context? I actually would like it if all Labels could be expressed as something close to situation 3 (but with a narrower gap between SFSymbol and Text).

Here is some code to demonstrate this problem:

```
struct LabelInPickerLayout: View {
    @State private var selection = 2
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("Choice", selection: $selection) {
                Label("First Item", systemImage: "1.circle").tag(1)
                Label("Second Item", systemImage: "2.circle").tag(2)
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)
            .labelsHidden()
            
            Section("almost desired look") {
                Label("First Item", systemImage: "1.circle")
            }
        }
    }
}
```